# Retrieving transaction hash in all blocks after fast sync

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, synchronization, fast-sync

I have set up an ethereum node using fast syncmode. I want to retrieve all the transaction hashes and the recipient between a range of blocks, let's say 0 - 13000. Will I be able to retrieve the required information using this fast sync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take into account that `fast` syncmode is default options, answer yes, you can retrieve all blocks, transaction.